# Gambler fallacy and probability of tossing coins

Tags: probability, gambling

Q. Three coins are tossed simultaneously 100 times with the following frequencies of different outcomes:

[image]

If the three coins are simultaneously tossed again, compute the compute the probability of :

(i) 2 heads coming up.

If I consider gambler's fallacy, answer of (i) should be $\frac{3}{8}$.

But, the solution I got from internet says, the probability of event (i) = $\frac{36}{100}$.

Here is a link to the solution: https://byjus.com/question-answer/three-coins-are-tossed-simultaneously-100-times-with-the-following-frequencies-of-different-outcomes-begin/

**Why gambler's fallacy hasn't been considered in the above solution?**

Comment: If you assume it is a fair coin then the answer is indeed 3/8, independent of the past. The solution in that link is just using the past empirical frequencies as if they are the true probabilities.

Comment: You're answer assumes you know the coins are fair.  Without any knowledge of that, the best you can say is that the 36/100 is an unbiased estimate for the probability of getting 2 heads in one toss of the 3 coins.  So it's the best guess you have at this point.